# Discord.js interval is not cleared

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm using my Discord bot to give members money by updating the database when they enter the voice channel. But even if they leave the voice channel, my bot still runs the function to give them more money. Although I'm using `clearInterval`, the interval is not cancelled.

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
  if (!oldState.channelID && newState.channelID) {
    oldState.member.roles.add("845279222590472253")

    var interval = setInterval(() => {
      db2.add(`para_${newState.member.user.id}`, 60)
    }, 5000);

  }
  else if (oldState.channelID && !newState.channelID) {
      oldState.member.roles.remove("845279222590472253");
      clearInterval(interval)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, `var` is scoped to the function and the variable `interval` is only available inside the function it's created in.

On every `voiceStateUpdate` you're calling the callback function that defines a new variable. It means, if someone connects, you start a new interval, the variable `interval` is only available inside that function. If the same member disconnects, a new `voiceStateUpdate` event is fired with a new callback function and a new (`undefined`) `interval` variable.

Check out the snippet below:

```js
function gimmeMoney(oldState, newState) {
  if (!oldState && newState) {
    var interval = setInterval(() => console.log('Add money'), 2000)
    console.log('Interval started to add money', {
      interval
    })
  } else if (oldState && !newState) {
    console.log('Clearing', {
      interval
    })
    // as interval is undefined, you can't clear it
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
}

console.log('Connect to voice channel')
gimmeMoney(false, true)
console.log('Wait for 6 seconds before we disconnect...')

let timeLeftBeforeClear = 6
const countdown = setInterval(() => {
  timeLeftBeforeClear -= 1
  console.log()

  if (timeLeftBeforeClear <= 0) {
    clearInterval(countdown)
    console.log('Time to disconnect...')
    return gimmeMoney(true, false)
  }
}, 1000)
```

If you run the snippet above, you could see that the interval ID is undefined when you want to clear the interval, so it doesn't do anything and the interval keeps running.

To solve this, you need to store the interval ID outside of the function. You can store these IDs in an object, a map, or a Discord [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection). If you use a collection, you can add a new interval ID to the collection with the member's ID as the key when someone connects. When the same member disconnects, you can [`get`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get) their interval ID by using their member ID.

Check out the working code below:

```js
// create a new collection to store the interval IDs
const intervals = new Discord.Collection();

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
  if (!oldState.channelID && newState.channelID) {
    oldState.member.roles.add('845279222590472253').catch(console.error);

    // set up a new interval and grab the returned ID
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      db2.add(`para_${newState.member.user.id}`, 60);
    }, 5000);
    // add a new element in the collection with the member's ID as the key
    intervals.set(oldState.member.id, interval);
  } else if (oldState.channelID && !newState.channelID) {
    oldState.member.roles.remove('845279222590472253').catch(console.error);
    
    // get the interval ID from the collection by the member's ID
    const interval = intervals.get(oldState.member.id);
    clearInterval(interval);
    // don't forget to remove it from the collection too
    intervals.delete(oldState.member.id);
  }
});
```